# Частота встречаемости делителей чисел

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм

Как наиболее быстро найти частоту встречаемости делителей у последовательности чисел (кроме делителя `1`)? Например, для чисел `4,7,10,12` результатом должно быть `2 - 3, 3 - 1, 4 - 2, 5 - 1, 6 - 1, 7 - 1, 10 - 1, 12 - 1`. Находить делители каждого числа, а потом подсчитывать сколько раз они встречаются, - слишком медленно (судя по профайлу).

Comment: А как находите делители и подсчитываете их? Может, просто реализация неудачная? "Волшебной пули", чтобы так взять и махом посчитать делители для произвольной последовательности, нет.

Comment: @MBo просто в цикле - если остаток от деления 0, то +1 к встречаемости делителя

Comment: @MBo может как-то можно не перебирать все делители, ведь если у нас, например, есть делитель 4, то мы знаем что также будет и делитель 2

Comment: Первое что приходит на ум- это факторизация всех чисел, но это дорогая операция

Comment: @arnold  Да, можно хранить таблицы найденных делителей и использовать их, но видится, что это дорогая операция.

Comment: А какое ограничение на размер числа?

Comment: @VTT числа 32 или 64 неотрицательные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативная идея: На каждой итерации сначала находить только простые делители каждого числа (которых будет сильно меньше, чем вообще делителей). Затем делить число на произведение найденных простых делителей. Затем снова искать какие из простых чисел найденных на предыдущем этапе являются делителями оставшегося числа. Повторять пока число не сойдет на нет. Таким образом у нас будет пачка массивов с простыми делителями, причем в каждом следующем массиве некоторые могут повторяться. На основе этих массивов попарным перемножением генерируем все делители.